# Custom Navbar Icon stuck inside a circle

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, icons, navbar

I created custom navbar icons and they show up. They are stuck inside a circle though. Is there any chance to get the icon bigger out of the query-mobile built in circle?

Have a look at the following page to see what I mean:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120511013421/http://evangelich.de/test/#p5

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.icons .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner {
 padding-top: 40px !important;
 }
.icons .ui-btn ui-icon {
 width: 40px !important;
 height: 30px !important;
 margin-left: 0px !important;
 box-shadow: none !important; 
 -moz-box-shadow: none !important; 
 -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
 -webkit-border-radius: none !important; 
 border-radius: 10px !important;
 }
#msg .ui-icon {
 background: url(icons/msg.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
 background-size: 40px 30px;
}
#nibe .ui-icon {
 background: url(icons/nibe.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px 30px;
}
#yougent .ui-icon {
 background: url(icons/yougent.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px 30px;
}
 #musik .ui-icon {
 background: url(icons/musik.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: 40px 30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" class"="icons">
 <div data-role="navbar" class"="icons">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#p2" id="msg" data-icon="custom" data-transition="fade">Msg L.</a></li>
  <li><a href="#p3" id="nibe" data-icon="custom" data-transition="fade">Ni-Be</a></li>
 <li><a href="#p4" id="yougent" data-icon="custom" data-transition="fade">YouGen&dagger;         </a></li>
  <li><a href="#p5" id="musik" data-icon="custom" data-transition="fade">Musik</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Whats wrong? How can I change that?

Comment: This question should be tagged 'css'. Also it's not very clear what the problem is with your page, please edit your question and try to be very clear about exactly what problem you are seeing.